# Trying to install google analytics for android app - start method deprecated

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am installing google analytics and when i write the line of code:

```
tracker.start(UA-..., 10)
```

Eclipse gives a warning that start method is deprecated. Anyone has done this recently? Are there new set of instructions on how to install google analytics? I am unable to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Valeh that link still has the depreciated code in there.

@NoviceMe I had the same issue, you may have found it already but if it helps someone else. Its not going to brake your code but have a look at this page under the heading 'Depreciations'

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/08/new-google-analytics-sdk-for-android.html

it says:

> We are deprecating the start and stop methods in favor of the startNewSession and stopSession. The existing methods will continue to be in the library, so your applications will still work when you upgrade, but we highlight recommend you move to these new methods.

Previously where you had:

```
tracker.start("UA-YOUR-GA-ACC-NUM", intCallPeriod, getApplication());
tracker.stop();
```

You will have:

```
tracker.startNewSession("UA-YOUR-GA-ACC-NUM", intCallPeriod, getApplication());
tracker.stopSession();
```

hope it helps.